# How to know when a AWS Lambda fails because timeout and also when it is out of memory using Zappa

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm using [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa) and 
I have a process that feed my AWS Lambda Function (deployed with [Zappa](https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa)) and some times it is over fed (bug that I cannot prevent), this causes the lambda sometimes run out of memory and others it just keep running until it dies without finish the job.

I would like to know if there is a way to know when one this things happens.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you prevent this bug? If there is such a hard memory limit, is there a way to query the remaining memory left?

Comment: let say the process that over feed my aws lambda is a 3rd party code

Comment: I would assume there is an error returned. Could you not catch this error or create your own? example
try:
    push
except:
   wait

Comment: Furthermore, If you know the limit you could log the amount of data you're processing and keep a local count of how much more data you have to work with

Comment: If the Lambda function can detect these two situations then it can alert on them (for example by sending a notification to an SNS topic which you can subscribe to). Lambda functions can query how much processing time is left before timeout (context.getRemainingTimeInMillis()) and you can presumably use some app-specific metric for the other 'over-feeding' case.

Comment: I'm not sure if Lambda can detect any of this situations

Comment: If it cannot, then how do you know you're hitting the limit?

Comment: @AlexanderFernándezAnzardo when I see errors in Cloudwatch logs from lambdas running out of memory, I often see the message "Process exited before completing request". Try searching your Cloudwatch logs for "exited".